# Fluid divs spill over with border

Tags: css

I have 2 divs that are `float:left` and show side by side like this :

[image]

The CSS for them is :

```
.movie-activity-feed{
    background:#f87777;
    float:left;
    padding:1%;
    margin:1% 2.5%;
    width:46%;
}
```

And they occupy the whole row properly. But when I add a border like this :

```
border:2px solid #000;
```

The divs spill over like this :

I know thats because of the extra 8px of borders that is not available in the row.
But is there a way to declare my margins as `2.5% - 2px` or something?
In short, is there a way to have fixed width borders on my fluid divs (using %), without the design breaking?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I resolved this using Passerby's comment and this question about `box-sizing` : [Fluid CSS layout and Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306443/fluid-css-layout-and-borders?rq=1)

This allows me to happily add any padding/border to a fluid div without worrying.

Comment: Use a wrapper `div` with 2px padding and black background?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BKXTn/2/ ?

Comment: yes, box-sizing was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You just need to change your `margin-left` and `margin-right` from `2.5%` to `0.5%`

Here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKXTn/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="movie-activity-feed"></div>
<div class="movie-activity-feed"></div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.movie-activity-feed{
    background:#f87777;
    float:left;
    padding:1%;
    margin:1% 0.5%;
    width:46%;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: This is breaking at a zoom of 150% or more. I think you have decreased the margin enough, so a 2px border doesnt interfere. This is a good hack, but if I have another row below(which i actually do) that is twice the width, then the math doesnt add. http://jsfiddle.net/BKXTn/3/

Comment: Using a `min-width` property resolves this issue http://jsfiddle.net/BKXTn/4/ - @soundswaste

Answer (score 0):

try some css calculations

```
margin: 1px calc(2% - 10px);
```

- it will not work in mozilla